# No option for creating a maven project in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ide

This is screenshot from a list of available projects. You can follow: File/New/Other. But there is no option for choosing Maven Project.
I have Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers and Ubuntu 16.04

[screenshot of eclipse ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2WCU.png)

How to create a new maven project?

Comment: You may have an old version of Eclipse. I'm pretty sure that from Eclipse Mars version Maven integration is included in Eclipse Java EE installation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `Maven Integration for Eclipse` from the `Marketplace`.

1. Help->Eclipse Marketplace.
2. type 'maven' in the search box and install `Maven Integration for Eclipse`.

Answer (score 0):

Install m2eclipse plugin first, go to Window -> Preferences. Check "Maven" is enlisted at the left panel list.

or use the latest version of eclipse